# Ошибка при выполнении mysqli-запроса

Tags: php, mysqli

Доброго времени суток, дорогие форумчане. Пишу вам с просьбой о помощи, подскажите, кто сведущ и силён в PHP+MySQLi. :)

У меня есть код авторизации. При авторизации выполняется запрос в базу данных. Ошибка происходит на этапе выполнения запроса. Самое интересное, что раньше всё работало, возможно, что `mysqli` выдаёт какую-то ошибку (ранее ошибок не замечал) и поэтому критует (критует как раз-таки по системе выдачи ошибок). Вот, собственно, сам код, который отправляет запросы в б/д.

```
class Database extends mysqli
{
    protected $con;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->con            = $GLOBALS['database'];

        if (!isset($this->con['port'])) {
            $this->con['port'] = 3306;
        }

        parent::__construct($this->con['host'], $this->con['user'], $this->con['userpw'], $this->con['databasename'], $this->con['port'] or die('Connect Error ('.$my_con->connect_errno.') '.$my_con->connect_error));

        parent::set_charset("utf8");
        #parent::query("SET SESSION sql_mode = '';");
        parent::query("SET SESSION sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';");
    }

    public function query($resource)
    {
        $result = parent::query($resource) or die('Select Error ('.$mysqli->errno.') '.$mysqli->error);
        return $result;
    }
```

Ошибка:

```
Произошла ошибка:8!
Файл: /home/intro116/data/www/speedgaming.ru/includes/classes/class.Database.php, строка 24.
Текст ошибки: Undefined variable: mysqli
Произошла ошибка:8!
Файл: /home/intro116/data/www/speedgaming.ru/includes/classes/class.Database.php, строка 24.
Текст ошибки: Trying to get property of non-object
Произошла ошибка:8!
Файл: /home/intro116/data/www/speedgaming.ru/includes/classes/class.Database.php, строка 24.
Текст ошибки: Undefined variable: mysqli
Произошла ошибка:8!
Файл: /home/intro116/data/www/speedgaming.ru/includes/classes/class.Database.php, строка 24.
Текст ошибки: Trying to get property of non-object
Select Error ()
```

24-я строка, это

```
$result = parent::query($resource) or die('Select Error ('.$mysqli->errno.') '.$mysqli->error);
```

В чём моя ошибка? `parent::errno` не помогает. Выдаёт `Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'errno`'.

Я в принципе понимаю, что переменной `$mysqli` попросту не существует, но как решить проблему? Как вывести ошибки отправки запросов?

Заранее благодарю всех за помощь. :)
С уважением, Юрий.

Comment: @Etki спасибо огромное. Я ступил. :(

Переведите комментарий в ответ, помечу как правильный. И будет нам обоим счастье. :)

P.S.: насчёт расширения функционала - это было сделано для облегчения написания кода в движке. В этом файле содержится большое количество функций, которые часто вызываются на страницах движка, и дабы не писать их по 100500 раз, я вынес их в отдельный класс.

Comment: > P.S.: насчёт расширения функционала - это было сделано для облегчения написания кода в движке. В этом файле содержится большое количество функций, которые часто вызываются на страницах движка, и дабы не писать их по 100500 раз я вынес их в отдельный класс.

Ну так вот, это делается не так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что errno это не константа, а переменная. `$this->errno` используйте, и будет вам полусчастье. Счастье же будет, когда вы не будете расширять базовый класс подключения не относящимся к нему функционалом.